# Is there a function that returns true when a control is focused?

Tags: delphi

I wrote a mobile app. 
I have a login panel and edits has a label which is a placeholder. (email/password)

edits onclick method change visible of labels. i also have onkeyboardshow to change the position of login panel. So when the user click the tedit, keyboard shown but label's visible does not change. if i click again the tedit, label's visible change.

So i added a some code to change label's visible when the keyboardshown.

```
    procedure TformReg.FormVirtualKeyboardShown(Sender: TObject;
  KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect);
begin
  Rectangle1.Align:= TAlignLayout.Top;
  Rectangle1.Margins.Left:= Trunc((screenW-362)/2);
  Rectangle1.Margins.Right:= Trunc((screenW-362)/2);
  if email.SetFocus = true then
    lblEmail.Visible:= false
  else
    lblPassword.Visible:= false;   
end;
```

But this code does not work, i have to understand which edit is focused.  i am using delphi firemonkey xe6.

Error is incompitable types

Comment: Since when is [`SetFocus`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.SetFocus) a function ? Aren't you missing `then` ? It still makes me wonder how can people post 2 lines of code with 2 mistakes (don't take it personally). Could you [`edit your question`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26991798/edit) and post the exact code that you use, not just *"some code"*, please ?

Comment: Also, idiomatically you never write `if somebool = True then`, you always write `if somebool then`

Comment: @TLama - if you read between the lines, that was his question: "is there a function that returns true if a control is focused?"

Comment: Note that SetFocus cannot be use directly. You need to call first CanFocus. But even that will not work in all cases. CanFocus is  **BROKEN**  (or incomplete in Delphi). Please check this article on how to [fix it](https://gabrielmoraru.com/setfocus-is-broken-in-delphi/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be something like:

```
label1.Visible := edit1.Focused;
```

You can't test if something is "SetFocus" since SetFocus is a procedure that actually FOCUS some control, so you need to test if the control is FOCUSED.