# Delphi Android edit1.setfocus

Tags: android, delphi, rotation, setfocus

I want to read the conditions if edit1.setfocus. so if the screen is in rotation in landscape when edit1.setfocus in potrait mode, I can give a command.

```
if edit1.setfocus then
```

or

```
if edit1.Focused then
```

the command is not found on FMX. can you give me enlightenment? thank you

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991798/delphi-focus-controlling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `edit1.IsFocused` (e.g. `if edit1.IsFocused then` ...) to check if the field has focus. To set the focus on the field use `edit1.SetFocus;`.

Comment: OMG, it's really easy. I passed isfocused. Thank you very much Rohit.

Comment: I keep warning people not to use SetFocus without CanFocus! You do this in your code. You need to call first CanFocus otherwise your code could raise an exception if the control cannot be focused. But even that will not work in all cases. CanFocus is  **BROKEN**  (or incomplete in Delphi). Please check this article on how to [fix it](https://gabrielmoraru.com/setfocus-is-broken-in-delphi/)